# Function composition

Tags: calculus, functions

I'm looking over practice exam papers and i've came across function composition. I can't do it. I've been given some notes with predone ones but cannot get the hang off it

[image]

here are the predone ones

in a way they do make sense, from a third person perspective but as soon as they're gone and i've gotta answer it myself i'm clueless. I'd be really grateful if someone could lay some questions out with the basic steps for doing them. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just carefully evaluate from the inside out by substitution, checking that the value lies in the appropriate domain.

The $(g \circ h(3))=g(h(3))$ example makes no sense, as $h(3)$ is either $\text{true}$ or $\text{false}$, and $g$ is defined on the reals.

Another example, if $y=(h \circ f \circ g) (5) = h(f(g(5)))$.

Then $g(5) = 2 \cdot 5 +2 = 12$, so $y=h(f(12))$.

Now $f(12) = {12 \over 3}= 4$, so $y=h(4)$.

Finally, $h(4) = (4 < 10) = \text{true}$, so we have $y=\text{true}$.

Comment: thanks. So you recommend doing it in stages rather than all in the one line, since it becomes confusing?

Comment: @user113523: Yes, until you are comfortable with the process.

Comment: If g equals Z > R and you're looking for g*g then would this be not valid

Comment: You lost me there? What do you mean by if $g$ equals $Z > R$? Presumably $R$ is the set of all real numbers.

Comment: if this http://vvcap.net/db/WEEhNfC1OtSzpUrFYT9R.htp was Z>R instead rather than R>R would this be an invalid function?

Comment: This would still work, as in this case, if $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $g(x) \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: but i thought http://vvcap.net/db/Jmc1XIjIppEXBY-sR16b.htp

Comment: It depends on exactly how you define a function$ f : A \to B$. Sometimes it just means the collection of pairs $\{(x,f(x)) \}_{x \in A}$, sometimes it includes the range, so the functions $g:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ and $h:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x)=h(x) = x$ for all $x$ would be considered different. So, you need to see how exactly your instructor/book defines functions.